# What's the difference between 'How long will you stay?' and 'How long will you be staying?'

Tags: tense

I was wondering the difference between **'How will you pay?'**, **'How will you be paying'**,

Somebody told me as follows,

> **How will you pay?** - talks more about the ability to pay, can you pay for this
>   **How will you be paying?** - what you will be using to pay like cash, credit card, etc.

Now, I am wondering, what's the difference between

> **How long will you stay?**
>   **How long will you be staying?**

Comment: Both mean the same exact thing.

Comment: "How will you pay" can easily work in the second case as well, but because the second option is perceived as more polite, I think most customer service professionals lean towards it to be safe. Incidentally, if I want to question someone's ability to pay, I will ask "How are you going to pay for that?", which is probably the most impolite way to phrase the question (as it is an impolite question to begin with). The same goes for "How long are you going to stay?" This question would likely make a guest uncomfortable (but might get the hint across).

Answer (score 2):

In my own idiolect for sure, and I think also in my dialect, the two would be used in different contexts:

> How long will you stay *there*?
>
> How long will you be staying *here*?

If someone told me about a trip they intended to take to Europe, I might ask "How long will you stay?"

If someone from Europe had come to my town to visit family, I might ask "How long will you be staying?"

This is not a rigid distinction by any means, but a matter of frequency. I could also ask "How long will you be staying *there*?" but I wouldn't ask "How long will you stay *here*?" but "How long are you going to stay here?"

Answer (score 1):

> **How long will you stay?**

is an **informal** way of asking

> **How long will you be staying?**

which is more **formal** and **polite**. You would probably hear the latter **asked** at the **registration desk** of a hotel.  The latter also has a slightly **less sense of asking for certainty** than the former since the listener may not know the answer themselves (thus more polite)

Comment: In terms of etiquette, is probably only worth worrying about when you are speaking to your own guest.

Answer (score 0):

No difference in meaning as far as you are making an enquiry; you can use either the future simple or the future continuous.

But, to be more polite, it's better to use the latter (the future continuous).